# How to improve this bypass switch from floating/differential to grounded/single-ended with just one DPDT?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches, differential, analog-switch

This is for use in guitar onboard active electronics.  (i.e. battery powered, installed in the guitar.)  I want to be able to switch between:

- Differential input (to Op Amp circuit) with pickup coil floating.
- Bypass to output jack with pickup coil grounded at one end.

See the two configurations below. (Vs + Zs represents the pickup and its impedance).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBL8W2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The trick is that **I only have one DPDT switch available to do the bypass.**  I don't think it's possible (but correct me if I'm wrong) to fully bypass the active circuit with just one DPDT without loading the pickup down with either the differential amp's input impedance, or the "Other Stuff" output.  Since it's battery powered, I don't want to use an electromechanical relay.

So far this is the best I've come up with.  One pole of the "hard" switch (SW1) is used to select the output source (pickup or electronics); the other pole applies ground to either the pickup, or to the control input of a CMOS analog switch IC (which is otherwise pulled up to V+).  The analog switch (SW2) disconnects the Op Amp circuit from the pickup when its input is pulled high.  Sorry for the tangled layout. CircuitLab won't allow the two switch poles to be separated.

**How could this be improved?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTpDs2.png)</sup>

The analog switch would be MAX324 or similar, with both control inputs tied together:

[image: MAX324 Pinout and truth table]

A side note:   I think R1 and R2 could be combined in the floating configuration since it's all one series combination, but I left them separate in case they help in any possible answers.  I suppose it might also help a tiny bit with noise immunity since the wire from the pickup is just an unshielded twisted pair. (There's also a separate shield ground to its metal enclosure. It's a ca. 2007 Danelectro "lipstick" pickup FWIW.)

Comment: Not sure why you need the MAX324 at all, unless you're trying to save current, or if Zs is on the same order as R1 and R2.  It will still drive the op amp, presumably incorrectly (since one diff input is now grounded rather than Vref biased) but you don't use the output from that circuit in the direct pass-through mode anyway.  As long as it's disconnected form the output, it shouldn't matter what it's doing.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis guitar pickups have very high inductance which makes them sensitive to load impedance, usually requiring ~1 Megohm; for flat frequency response. Double-terminating could affect the tone.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis You're right that from an impedance standpoint I wouldn't need it on the end of the coil that gets pulled to ground by SW1.  However, that would end up drawing DC current through R4 & R2, and would load down the voltage divider (not drawn) that derives Vcm.

Comment: @BruceAbbott As it turns out, the combination of the pickup's inductance with its parasitic capacitance creates a resonant peak in the output which is part of each particular pickup's character.  Loading with a lower impedance tends to flatten the peak.  It might be more correct to say you need ~1 MΩ for "desirably un-flat" response!